# Which class object does findElement method return?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have just started learning selenium. I am unable to understand this point clearly.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
```

Does `findElement` return an object of the class implementing the `WebElement` interface?
If so which class object is it returning? Is it `HtmlUnitWebElement` class object?

Please clear this doubt of mine......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please look at the detailed explanation in below link:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html

The return type object is type of HtmlUnitWebElement and each object represents one HTML element.

You can find the detailed explanation of by clicking on findElement method also by clicking on the function name provided below.

Comment: since u said it returns Html unit WebElement i have changed WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.id("id")) this stmt to HtmlUnitWebElement e=driver.findElement(By.id("id")) but i am getting Type mismatch error:cannot convert webelemnt to htmlunitwebelement.y am i getting this error?any explanation.thanks in advance